# Python program not correctly reading a text file on program startup?

Tags: python, regex, bots, reddit, praw

I've been trying forever to get this program to work. It's a program for a reddit bot which replies to a comment with a picture of a snake when you leave a comment with the word "snekpic". Originally, when it replied to a comment, it would save the comment id in a list so that it does not reply multiple times to the comment. But that had a small issue because whenever the program restarted, it would start again with an empty list, and it would reply to all the comments it already replied to. So instead of a list, I'm saving the comment ids to a text file and reading the text file. It seems to be able to read the text file because it does not reply to a comment multiple times, but it has the same problem I had before. When I restart the program, it replies to all the comments that it already replied to. So for some reason, it is not properly reading the text file on startup. Here's the code:

```
import praw
import TagFinder as Tf
import re
import random

user_agent = "xxx 0.2 by /u/xxx and /u/xxx"
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=user_agent)

r.login(username='xxx', password='xxx')

possible_tags = ['standing', 'corn', 'ball', 'burmese', 'hognose', 'clothes', 'art', 'cool', 'funny', 'gif']

comment_regex = re.compile(r'(^snekpic)(\s+(\w+))?')

messages = {1: 'hissss', 2: 'snek?', 3: 'SNEK!', 4: 'sssss', 5: 'boop',
            6: 'slither slither', 7: 'Don\'t tread on me', 8: 'I am sssummoned.',
            9: 'Give me a mousssse please.', 10: 'BEEP ^BOOP BOP I AM ROBOSNEK', 11: 'Snek.'}

while True:
    all_comments = praw.helpers.comment_stream(r, 'test')
    for comment in all_comments:
        try:
            comment_text = comment.body.lower()
            mo = comment_regex.search(comment_text)

            with open('already_done.txt', 'a+') as already_done:
                already_done.seek(0)
                if comment.id not in already_done.read() and mo is not None and mo.group(3) is not None:
                    if mo.group(3) in possible_tags:
                        try:
                            comment.reply('[' + messages[random.randint(1, 11)] + '](' + Tf.search(mo.group(3)) + ')')
                            already_done.write(str(comment.id) + '\n')
                            already_done.seek(0)
                        except (praw.errors.InvalidComment, praw.errors.RateLimitExceeded):
                            pass
                    else:
                        try:
                            comment.reply('Thisss category does not exissst! [Here\'s a picture of a snek anyway!](' +
                                          Tf.search() + ')')
                            already_done.write(str(comment.id) + '\n')
                            already_done.seek(0)
                        except (praw.errors.InvalidComment, praw.errors.RateLimitExceeded):
                            pass
                    already_done.seek(0)
                elif comment.id not in already_done.read() and mo is not None and mo.group(3) is None:
                    try:
                        comment.reply('[' + messages[random.randint(1, 11)] + '](' + Tf.search() + ')')
                        already_done.write(str(comment.id) + '\n')
                        already_done.seek(0)
                    except (praw.errors.InvalidComment, praw.errors.RateLimitExceeded):
                        pass
                    already_done.seek(0)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

TagFinder is a separate program that returns a url. I found out that after you read a file, it moves the read cursor to the end of the file, so if you want to read it again, you have to use `seek(0)` to move the cursor back to the beginning. So I put `seek(0)` at the beginning of the `with` statement and after each time when the file is read or appended to (I'm not sure if appending moves the read cursor).

This program is actually for a high school programming class, so I asked for help and my teacher recommended writing a simpler version of the program and seeing if that worked. So I wrote the following short program

```
import time

while True:
    with open('already_done.txt', 'a+') as o:
        o.seek(0)
        if 'corn' in o.read():
            print('FOUND')
            o.write('\nFOUND')
        else:
            print('NOT FOUND')
            o.write('\nNOT FOUND')
    time.sleep(3)
```

and everything worked perfectly. It found the word "corn" in the text file on start up, and every 3 seconds, and it also kept writing to the file. Since this worked, I'm really stumped. I have no idea what could be going wrong in the bigger program. I'm open for any help or ideas.

PS: Sorry about the lack of comments. I'm planning on adding them once the program is functional. If anything is unclear, I'm happy to explain it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Instead of trying to search the file directly, you could load the entire file into a list when the program starts.  Then search the list instead of the file.  When you add a new comment id, append it to both the list and the file.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll do that if I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in this code:

```
if comment.id not in already_done.read()
```

If `comment.id` is an integer, this will always be True, because `read()` returns a character string.